# Assign tables a human-readable, and dynamically retrievable, title or alias in CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

For the purposes of creating dynamic menus for a CMS, I need to be able to retrieve both a given models' associations, and, for each of those associated models, a string that represents it in a human-digestible form. So for example, if I have an `Articles` table that has many `Hostedimages`, I can dynamically get that association information via

`$this->Articles->associations()->keys()`

But, this gives me the string `Hostedimages`, whereas, of course, for the UI I want `Hosted Images`.

I'm assuming that I can store this string somewhere in the `Hostedimages` model. Anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`keys()` should return all lowercased names IIRC, ie `hostedimages`, that's how association collections use them internally in order to ensure uniqueness.

Surely you could assign a value to a table object, but a table can be used in multiple associations, so that wouldn't work too well, and a table also doesn't need to know anything about the presentation layer.

Ideally you'd stick to the CakePHP naming conventions and use camel cased names, ie name your association/table `HostedImages`, then you could for example use the inflector on the association name:

```
$associations = $this->Articles->associations();
```

```
$readableNames = collection($associations)
    ->map(function (\Cake\ORM\Association $association) {
        return \Cake\Utility\Inflector::humanize(
            \Cake\Utility\Inflector::underscore($association->getName())
        );
    })
    ->toList();
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > CakePHP at a Glance > CakePHP Conventions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html)**
- **[Cookbook > Inflector](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/inflector.html)**